# DWM1000 & Raspberry PI

Tags: raspberry-pi, indoor-positioning-system

I'm trying to find the distance between 2 Raspberry PIs based on this document:
https://thingtype.com/blog/using-a-dwm1000-module-with-a-raspberry-pi-and-python/

I use 2 Raspberry PI 3B+, one as an anchor and one as a tag. When I run DW1000RangingAnchor.py script on the anchor device and DW1000RangingTag.py on the tag device, I get the proper unique ID on each device but it shows the distance over 5 million kilometers! The real distance is 2 meters. The distance value changes between  5,158,633,200.00 m and  5,158,641,000.00 m even if I don't move the tag on anchor. If I move them I don't see any logical changes on the distance. Here are some Distance samples reported by the anchor:
Distance: 5158636761.94 m
reset inactive
reset inactive
reset inactive
Distance: 5158635529.43 m
reset inactive
reset inactive
reset inactive
Distance: 5158635295.80 m
reset inactive
reset inactive
reset inactive
Distance: 5158635459.03 m
reset inactive
reset inactive
reset inactive
Distance: 5158635537.69 m
reset inactive
reset inactive
reset inactive
Distance: 5158635687.96 m
reset inactive
reset inactive
reset inactive
Distance: 5158635301.28 m


If I turn off the tag, the anchor doesn't show the distance anymore, it proves that the anchor receives signals from the tag.
Initially I used 2 Raspberry PI 3B+ as anchor and tag then I changed the tag to Arduino Pro mini, then changed the anchor to RPi2, tried all the combinations and got the same result. I also tried different DMW1000 chips, no luck.
Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't notice the article below.

**＊ Note that distances are not really accurate above 70 meters and below 45 centimeters**

So maybe you can put the one pi to the far distance.I think the accurate above 70 meters and below 45 centimeters is OK. In general, it will not be needed to be larger or smaller than this interval.

If you have any problem , please let me know .

Thanks you !

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I mentioned in my post, the real distance was 2 meters. I tried to move the PIs and tested different distances but I didn't get the right result.